# How to check if an object is a primitive data type in Rust?

Tags: rust, primitive, primitive-types

I am a C++ developer who is making the transition to Rust, I am looking for something analogous to
`bool isPrimitive = std::is_fundamental<varType>`.  I haven't had much luck in finding a standard way to do this.  I suppose I could hand roll my own function that does a bunch of OR's with all of the Rust primitive types.  But I was hoping there is already something out there.
Example

```
let is_primitive = someFunction<i32> //returns true
let is_primitive_1 = someFunction<Vec<u32>> //returns false
let is_primitive_2 = someFunction<someStruct> //returns false
let is_primitive_3 = someFunction<(bool, f32)> //returns false
```

Comment: Added an example of what I'm looking for.  If you're familiar with C++, I am loooking for the rust equivalent of std::is_fundamental
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I think (my best guess) what you're trying here is to have a parameter function that only accepts "fundamentals"? That's not how it works in Rust. You have to describe what that type `T` is able to do, e.g. Adding numbers or calling `foo` on it, by using a constraint, e.g. `T: Foo` where `Foo` is a trait. You may take a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics.html

Comment: I am creating a telemetry function for some custom software and packaging the binary data for others to process.  I need them to be able to tell when the data type is primitive, or if the described type has other fields they need to pull out of the binary file.

Comment: Since your usage examples are so simple and yield obvious values, would you mind to add another example where you don't name a type explicitly, please? Do you want to have "templated" usages? A [example] would be optimal.

Comment: "primitiveness" is not a well defined quality. What exactly does it mean to you for a type to be "primitive" or "fundamental"? Rust does not natively have such a notion.

Comment: Rust does have a concept of primitiveness. https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html
```
Primitive types:
Boolean — true or false
Numeric — integer and float
Textual — char and str
Never — ! — a type with no values
```
I will provide an example where the types aren't hardcoded.  But those are minimum working examples.  I think the answer I am getting to is that I need to hand roll something and that no obvious pre existing solutions are out there. I need a function that returns true if a type that is passed in matches the description of Primitive as is found in the link above.

Comment: Even so, can you elaborate on _why_ you need to check if something meets that particular definition of primitiveness? There might very well be an elegant, idiomatic solution to the _higher level_ problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: For exmaple, someone coming from C++ might think that they need to check for primitiveness so that they can safely (i.e. without weird aliasing effects and without high memory cost) copy a value of that type. In Rust, though you'd just use the `Copy` trait for that, which all primitive types implement.

Comment: No, Rust does not have a concept of primitiveness. The reference describes one way of categorizing types, for humans, but Rust the language does not care whether a type is a tuple or an integer. [The book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html?highlight=primitive#compound-types) also refers to tuples and arrays as being "primitive". [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives.html) adds `()` to the list. None of these categorizations should be construed as defining a language level distinction between "primitive" and "non-primitive" types.

Comment: Anyway, please [edit] the question to show exactly what definition of "primitive" you are using.

Comment: Working on a editing the question with rust code that will compile, I will update.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too quick with an answer. It seems that  in Rust it is currently not possible to provide a default implementation for a fallback case (basically say: for each type T - return false). This is gonna be covered by this *specialization* feature eventually: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md

Answer (score 4):

You write

> I need them to be able to tell when the data type is primitive, or if the described type has other fields they need to pull out of the binary file.

This property will be determined by *the design of the format of that binary file*, not by Rust's own built-in types. Therefore, you should arrange to be able to ask the data serializer this question about its encoding, not to ask Rust.